# Find sets on which $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos(nx)}{e^{nx}}$ is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I need to find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos(nx)}{e^{nx}}$$

is pointwise convergent and characterise sets on which the series is uniformly convergent.

Now, I think that the series is pointwise convergent for every $x > 0$. Because in that case:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos(nx)}{e^{nx}} \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{e^{nx}} \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2} \rightarrow \text{converges}$$

If $x = 0$ then we get:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos(nx)}{e^{nx}} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} 1 = \infty$$

if $x < 0$:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos(nx)}{e^{-nx}} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} e^{nx}\cos(nx) = \infty$$

I don't know how to find sets on which the series is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Use the Weierstrass test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison test above for pointwise convergence is not valid since the cosine term changes sign.  But you can easily fix this as an absolute convergence comparison test, since $\left|\frac{\cos nx}{e^{nx}} \right| \leqslant  e^{-nx}$ and for $x > 0$ the series $\sum e^{-nx}$ is a convergent geometric series.

If $x \in [a,\infty)$ where $a > 0$, then $\displaystyle\left|\frac{\cos n x}{e^{nx}} \right| \leqslant e^{-na}$ and the series converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test on $[a,\infty)$.

Obviously, the series diverges for any $x \leqslant 0$ as you showed.

Finally we can show that the series fails to converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.
Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n = \pi/(6n)\in (0,\infty)$, we have $1/2 < \cos kx_n \leqslant \sqrt{3}/2$ for $n < k \leqslant 2n$, and

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{\cos kx_n}{e^{kx_n}}\right| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{\cos kx_n}{e^{kx_n}} > n \cdot \frac{1/2}{e^{2nx_n}} = \frac{n}{2e^{\pi/3}} \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow\infty,$$

and the series fails to converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ by violation of the uniform Cauchy criterion.

Comment: OK, I think your hint gets the job done since the series on the right is uniformly convergent. However, can I cover the whole set of $x \in (0, \infty)$ with that kind of thinking? Since for every x I can always choose smaller a...

Comment: @mathbb: No - the uniform convergence does not extend to $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Uniform convergence on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a > 0$ does not necessarily imply uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: So there is a point that is too close to $0$. But can it be expressed without any variables (I mean is that 'breaking point' exactly known or is it just possible that it exists somewhere)?

Comment: @mathbb: The convergence is not uniform if $x$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ basically because the series diverges when $x = 0$. It is impossible to make $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty f_k(x)\right| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$ where $N$ is independent of $x$ as a result.  I'll add a proof of non-unifom convergence above.

Comment: There is no "breaking point" close to $0$.  The breaking point is $0$.